# Approved permissions not showing in "My permissions and features" section on Facebook developers dashboard after business verification

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My app needs to fetch the user_friends from Facebook and the Facebook app review process has approved the app also for the permissions. As next step, I have also done the business verification and on Facebook dashboard, it shows verified. But once I change the app status from Development to Live, user_friends permission is not shown in My permissions and features. Does anyone has idea of this. 
Please find the images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you signed the "Additional Contract Signing" part of the user_friends permission review?

Comment: Where do I get that Contract? I am done with the business details

Comment: 2nd screen shot, click on the Requires Additional Contract Signing link.